# aggregation in Tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have this sql query:

```
select ct.ID, t.Tag from links ct
inner join tags t on ct.ID_TAG = t.ID_TAG
```

returning this resultset:

```
ID                                   | Tag
--------------------------------------------------
3e39e18a-f741-4ab8-9225-b11d8a6df440 | apps 
3e39e18a-f741-4ab8-9225-b11d8a6df440 | testing 
dbfa053c-be7a-45f9-9dba-02fd5407a0e3 | tools 
dbfa053c-be7a-45f9-9dba-02fd5407a0e3 | apps 
dbfa053c-be7a-45f9-9dba-02fd5407a0e3 | testing 
cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a | bruzzo 
cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a | octocats 
cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a | github 
ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a | bruzzo 
ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a | octocats 
ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a | github 
b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d | bruzzo 
b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d | octocats 
b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d | github 
8c77dd17-466f-4a6e-916b-6c563d016fd4 | octocats 
d8a524cb-56b6-4d43-b136-3e1a923b9920 | octocats 
a460912d-ade9-433d-9d56-9d841480c1bb | gaziano
```

Now I need to retrieve all the IDs associated with both tags "octocats" and "github", so I expect:

```
cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a
ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a
b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d
```

What is the most efficient way to retrieve the requested resultset? Also consider that I could have more than two tags to search for matching IDs.

EDIT: For all people suggesting 'IN' statement, this is the result (not what I need):

```
cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a | octocats 
cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a | github 
ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a | octocats 
ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a | github 
b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d | octocats 
b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d | github 
8c77dd17-466f-4a6e-916b-6c563d016fd4 | octocats 
d8a524cb-56b6-4d43-b136-3e1a923b9920 | octocats
```

I don't need the last two to be included, they only match 'octocats' but not 'github'.

Comment: `WHERE t.Tag IN ('octocats', 'github')` and it's not aggregation

Comment: That's not what I need. My requirement is to fetch IDs associated with both tags, not just only one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ct.ID
from links ct
inner join tags t on ct.ID_TAG = t.ID_TAG
where t.Tag in ('github', 'octocats')
group by ct.ID
having count(distinct t.tag) = 2;
```

This should give you the id's that have both tags

Answer (score 0):

syntax wise simplest is to do `in`

```
where t.Tag in ('github', 'octocats')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/):

Following solution is based on PIVOT operator:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    Tag VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT @MyTable (ID, Tag)
SELECT '3e39e18a-f741-4ab8-9225-b11d8a6df440', 'apps '
UNION ALL SELECT '3e39e18a-f741-4ab8-9225-b11d8a6df440', 'testing '
UNION ALL SELECT 'dbfa053c-be7a-45f9-9dba-02fd5407a0e3', 'tools '
UNION ALL SELECT 'dbfa053c-be7a-45f9-9dba-02fd5407a0e3', 'apps '
UNION ALL SELECT 'dbfa053c-be7a-45f9-9dba-02fd5407a0e3', 'testing '
UNION ALL SELECT 'cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a', 'bruzzo '
UNION ALL SELECT 'cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a', 'octocats '
UNION ALL SELECT 'cc7241a6-3054-4589-a011-55c3baa43d8a', 'github '
UNION ALL SELECT 'ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a', 'bruzzo '
UNION ALL SELECT 'ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a', 'octocats '
UNION ALL SELECT 'ae85d29d-9ca3-43c9-8345-d192eacd052a', 'github '
UNION ALL SELECT 'b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d', 'bruzzo '
UNION ALL SELECT 'b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d', 'octocats '
UNION ALL SELECT 'b682fc38-382d-4f5a-878a-e9a24f77587d', 'github '
UNION ALL SELECT '8c77dd17-466f-4a6e-916b-6c563d016fd4', 'octocats '
UNION ALL SELECT 'd8a524cb-56b6-4d43-b136-3e1a923b9920', 'octocats '
UNION ALL SELECT 'a460912d-ade9-433d-9d56-9d841480c1bb', 'gaziano ';

SELECT z.ID, z.octocats, z.github
FROM
(
    SELECT  x.ID, x.Tag
    FROM    @MyTable x
    WHERE   x.Tag IN ('octocats', 'github')
) y
PIVOT(COUNT(y.Tag) FOR y.Tag IN([octocats], [github])) z
WHERE z.octocats > 0 AND z.github > 0;
```